# Excel to Google Spreadsheet problem

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

I emailed an Excel spreadsheet as an attachment to my Gmail account.
I then chose open as a Google Spreadsheet.
When I opened the Google Spreadsheet, it was missing some formulas and had changed some formulas. However, when the same attachment was downloaded and opened with Excel, the spreadsheet had all formulas correct. The formulas were basic addition/subtraction/division formulas, nothing exotic.

I emptied my cache with both Goog and CCleaner, rinsed and repeated. The same result.
I've performed this action over 2 dozen times in the past without a problem.

Is there a current Google Spreadsheet issue/bug?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make sure that MS Excel 2010 files are properly converted and still work in Google Spreadsheets, then **don't** use the following formula's:

```
AMORDEGRC
AMORLINC
AREAS
ASC
AVERAGEIF
AVERAGEIFS
BAHTTEXT
BESSELI
BESSELJ
BESSELK
BESSELY
BETADIST
BETAINV
CALL
CELL
CHIDIST
CHIINV
CHITEST
CLEAN
COMPLEX
CONVERT
COUNTIFS
CUBEKPIMEMBER
CUBEMEMBER
CUBEMEMBERPROPERTY
CUBERANKEDMEMBER
CUBESET
CUBESETCOUNT
CUBEVALUE
DELTA
ERF
ERROR.TYPE
EUROCONVERT
FDIST
FINV
FTEST
GAMMADIST
GAMMAINV
GESTEP
GETPIVOTDATA
IMABS
IMAGINARY
IMARGUMENT
IMCONJUGATE
IMCOS
IMDIV
IMEXP
IMLN
IMLOG10
IMLOG2
IMPOWER
IMPRODUCT
IMREAL
IMSIN
IMSQRT
IMSUB
IMSUM
INFO
IS 
ISPMT
JIS
LOOKUP
ODDFPRICE
ODDFYIELD
ODDLPRICE
ODDLYIELD
PHONETIC
REGISTER.ID
RTD
SQL.REQUEST
SUMIFS
TDIST
TIMEVALUE
TINV
TTEST
TYPE
VDB
WEEKNUM
YIELDMAT
```

Reference: [MS EXCEL vs. GOOGLE SPREADSHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFJ4ZHhGTUI2Sm0zcVg1SjdHd0VxSkE&usp=sharing)

Comment: Jacob,Thanks for your response. That's an amazing list. Hard to believe that's an acceptable situation to Goog Doc users.

Comment: @lou1 It accounts the other way around as well. Did it help you?

Comment: @lou12 was my answer of help?